# How to find a timestamp difference by sql in the different rows of the MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have an audit table that has a job id, status, and timestamp.
The statuses and timestamps are shown by the following query:

```
select aud.job_instance_id, aud.insert_ts, aud.job_status_from, aud.job_status_to
from job_instance_audit aud
where (job_status_from = 1 and job_status_to = 2) or (job_status_from = 2 and job_status_to = 3)
order by aud.job_instance_id desc limit 1000;
```

The results for 2 rows for one job_instance_id  are as follows:

job_instance_id, insert_ts, job_status_from, job_status_to

371376, 2020-09-11 12:37:58, 2, 3

371376, 2020-09-11 12:35:46, 1, 2

I am interested in the difference of time between these 2 timestamps for the same job, one timestamp is for job_status_to=3, another one is for job_status_to=2. Can I find this difference  by a SQL query?

Comment: Do you always find a maximum of two rows per job? If so you can use `LAG()`.

Comment: It can be up to 10 rows for the same job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select job_instance_id, 
       timestampdiff(
         second,
         max(case when job_status_to = 2 then insert_ts end),
         max(case when job_status_to = 3 then insert_ts end)
       ) difference_in_secs
from job_instance_audit
where (job_status_from = 1 and job_status_to = 2) or (job_status_from = 2 and job_status_to = 3)
group by job_instance_id
```

Comment: Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908914/how-to-find-maximum-timestamp-differences-by-sql-between-the-current-date-and-au

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the time difference between two rows by peeking at another row using the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` functions.

For example, using `LEAD()`:

```
select
  aud.job_instance_id, 
  aud.insert_ts, 
  aud.job_status_from, 
  aud.job_status_to,
  timestampdiff(
    second, 
    lead(aud.insert_ts) over(
      partition by aud.job_instance_id 
      order by aud.job_instance_id desc),
    aud.insert_ts
  ) as diff
from job_instance_audit aud
where job_status_from = 1 and job_status_to = 2 
   or job_status_from = 2 and job_status_to = 3
order by aud.job_instance_id desc 
limit 1000
```

The `OVER()` clause must specify the exact rules on how to find the lead (or lag) row.