# How to find maximum timestamp differences by sql between the current date and audit timestamp of the MYSQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have an audit table that has a job id, job_status_to, job_status_from and timestamp.
The statuses and timestamps are shown by the following query:

```
select aud.job_instance_id, aud.insert_ts, aud.job_status_from, aud.job_status_to
from job_instance_audit aud
where (job_status_from = 1 and job_status_to = 2) or (job_status_from = 2 and job_status_to = 3)
order by aud.job_instance_id desc limit 1000;
```

The results for 2 rows for one job_instance_id  are as follows:

```
job_instance_id,           insert_ts, job_status_from, job_status_to
         371376, 2020-09-11 12:37:58,               2,             3
         371376, 2020-09-11 12:35:46,               1,             2
```

I can easily find the difference in minutes for all rows in the job_instance_audit  table

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, insert_ts,NOW()) from job_instance_audit  
where job_status_to=2 order by job_instance_id  desc limit 10000;
```

However, I am interested in the difference of time between NOW() and the timestamp in the table only if the maximum job_status_to for a particular job does not exceed 2, i.e. the job is still in the status 2 and have not passed to the status 3.  Also, I would like to see only the results with the difference greater than 4 minutes ordered by the difference starting from the maximum.

Can I find this difference  by a SQL query?

Comment: can you show us the the base data as well to achieve a [mre]

Comment: And specify precise MySQL version - it is important for this task.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described, something like this should do it:

```
SELECT job_instance_id,
       insert_ts,
       job_status_from,
       job_status_to,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, insert_ts, NOW()) AS time_diff_mins
FROM   job_instance_audit
WHERE  job_status_to = 2
       AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, insert_ts, NOW()) > 4
       AND job_instance_id NOT IN (SELECT job_instance_id
                                   FROM   job_instance_audit
                                   WHERE  job_status_to > 2)
ORDER  BY 5 DESC
```